# Can set the div content with jquery

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net

Why can't I put dynamic text on a div called foo? The following is on a metho in the asp.net codebehind.

```
StringBuilder script = new StringBuilder();
        script.Append("<script type='text/javascript'>");
        script.Append("                                $(document).ready(function () {");
        script.Append("                                    $('<div id=foo></div>').appendTo('body');");
        script.Append("                                    var dlg = $('#foo');");
        script.Append("                                    dlg.dialog({");
        script.Append("                                         autoOpen: true,");
        script.Append("                                         resizable: false,");
        script.Append("                                         draggable: false,");
        script.Append("                                         modal: true,");
        script.Append("                                         title: 'Información',");
        script.Append("                                         width: 400,");
        script.Append("                                         height: 200,");
        script.Append("                                         buttons: {");
        script.Append("                                            'Cerrar': function () {");
        script.Append("                                            $(this).dialog('close');");
        script.Append("                                         }");
        script.Append("                                       }");
        script.Append("                                   });");
        script.Append("     $('#foo').html(<p>"+info+"</p>);");
        script.Append("                                });");

        script.Append("</script>");

        ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "launchModalWindow", script.ToString());
```

The problem is in this line:

```
script.Append("     $('#foo').html(<p>"+info+"</p>);");
```

Comment: Not *immediately* seeing the problem. Note, though, that instead of `$('<div id=foo></div>').appendTo('body');` followed by `var dlg = $('#foo');`, you can simply and more directly do `var dlg = $('<div id=foo></div>').appendTo('body');`

Comment: Perhaps the document is not fully ready when that line is executed and the div `foo` doesn't exist yet? Actually yes, this is the answer. I didn't see you are creating `foo` on `document.ready`, which will be before this line executes.

Comment: Note that the `language` attribute of `script` tags has been deprecated for more than a decade. The relevant attribute is [`type`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/the-script-element.html#attr-script-type), but if the script is JavaScript, you don't need to specify it at all, the default is `"text/javascript"` if `type` is omitted.

Comment: @Ivan__83: The code presented *creates* the "foo" element, appending it to `document.body` in the `ready` handler. Qpirate has [found the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11395336/157247).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Put the dynamic text like that:

```
script.Append("                                    $('<div id=foo class=vw1>"+ info +"</div>').appendTo('body');");
```

Answer (score 5):

```
script.Append("$('#foo').html('<p>hola</p>');");
```

is outside the context of document.ready.

move it up one line so it is run when the page is ready for it to be loaded.

```
StringBuilder script = new StringBuilder();
    script.Append("<script language='javascript'>");
    script.Append("                                $(document).ready(function () {");
    script.Append("                                    $('<div id=foo></div>').appendTo('body');");
    script.Append("                                    var dlg = $('#foo');");
    script.Append("                                    dlg.dialog({");
    script.Append("                                         autoOpen: true,");
    script.Append("                                         resizable: false,");
    script.Append("                                         draggable: false,");
    script.Append("                                         modal: true,");
    script.Append("                                         title: 'Información',");
    script.Append("                                         width: 400,");
    script.Append("                                         height: 200,");
    script.Append("                                         buttons: {");
    script.Append("                                            'Cerrar': function () {");
    script.Append("                                            $(this).dialog('close');");
    script.Append("                                         }");
    script.Append("                                       }");
    script.Append("                                   });");
    script.Append("$('#foo').html('<p>hola</p>');");
    script.Append("                                });");
    script.Append("</script>");
```

Comment: Thank you!! It worked. But now I have another issue. I need to put a dynamic text in this dialog. I'm going to update the thread.

Comment: However I don't undertand why this line must be in the ready context. Can you explain me?

Comment: *"However I don't undertand why this line must be in the ready context."* Because the code in the `ready` handler happens **after** the code outside the `ready` handler, even though that code is further down in the source: http://jsbin.com/izubad

Comment: It depends on what you mean by "Dynamic", is this text coming from the server (bound at the same time as this code is being run) or via AJAX, both are slightly different.

Answer (score -1):

should be `<div id="foo">`.  You are missing quotes.

Also, you want to do your update to #foo in a

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#foo').html('<p>hola</p>');
}
```

Comment: *"You are missing quotes."* The quotes are [completely optional](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#attributes-0) if the value doesn't contain space, `"`, `'`, `=`, `<`, `>`, or `\``.

Comment: thanks, sometimes I forget you can do bad html and it will allow it

Comment: @ Rocky: It's not "bad." It's entirely according to spec. (And it's **always** been allowed. HTML4 spec circa: 1999, which is the earliest any kind of rigor was applied: http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/intro/sgmltut.html#didx-attribute Or 3.2: *"HTML allows CDATA attributes to be unquoted provided the attribute value contains only letters (a to z and A to Z), digits (0 to 9), hyphens (ASCII decimal 45) or, periods (ASCII decimal 46)."* ref: http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html32)

Comment: ok, but i will still discourage my developers from doing this.

Comment: @ Rocky: Yeah, I don't do it either. :-)